# How can i get the error in a two way anova analysis in sigmaplot?

Tags: sigmaplot

I'm trying to find the error in a two way anova analysis in sigmaplot. However, my analysis only gives me the residual value. How can i get the error?

Thank you all!

Comment: Please include reproducible code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I only uses sigmaplot the user friendly interface. I didn't write any code...